# How to configure settings to be overridden for multiple languages, in VSCode?

Tags: text-editors, visual-studio-code

VSCode allows users to set [language specific editor settings](https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getstarted/settings/#language-specific-editor-settings), by doing something like this:

```json
"[scss]": {
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

But this is not enough, because: what if I need to set the **same rules for CSS**? *- don't you make me duplicate the code...*

**what I tried, with no success:**

```json
"[scss,css]": {
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

```json
"[scss|css]": {
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

```json
"[*.{scss,css}]": {
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

```json
"[scss][css]": {
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

Comment: Not supported AFAIK :( I found [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/75733) weird issue, but what they are reporting is not working for me.

Comment: But this might be worth a feature request. For example, I like to use the prettier plugin on multiple languages like js, jsx, ts, tsx, and so on.

Comment: @Elias cast your vote in this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/51935

Answer (score 1):

This is now supported in [1.63](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_63#_multiple-language-specific-editor-settings)

```json
"[javascript][typescript]": {
  "editor.maxTokenizationLineLength": 2500
}
```